# Instagram API response with users not in caption

Tags: rest, api, instagram-api

I want to know what users are tagged in a photo on Instagram, who don't appear in the caption.

Anyone know if this is possible? That is, does the response contain users that are tagged, but that are not physically in the caption text?

https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property you probably want is called `users_in_photo`. It is an array which contains an array of `user` objects who've been tagged in the photo. It also contains the geometric coordinates in the photo that the user has been "tagged" at.

Here is an example response using the `/media/MEDIA_ID` endpoint:

Endpoint Documentation -> https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/#get_media

```
{
    "data": {
        "users_in_photo": [{
            "user": {
                "username": "kevin",
                "full_name": "Kevin S",
                "id": "3",
                "profile_picture": "..."
            },
            "position": {
                "x": 0.315,
                "y": 0.9111
            }
        }],
        // rest of object...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for are username mentions in captions and comments, API does not return this list in API, you will have to search for `@usernames` in the caption string. 
You will have to make a separate API call to get the comments in post (u can only get latest 120), and do a manual string search in each of the comments.

`users_in_photo` in API response will have an array of users that are actually tagged on photo, not username mentions

Comment: I think the original question said "users are tagged in a photo [...] who don't appear in the caption", which sounds to me like the tagged users, and specifically NOT the ones in the comment.